# Object is moving more than it should

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for Food:

```
exports.Food = function(x, y) {
this.MOVE_X_FROM_POSITION = 10;
this.ACCELERATION = 0.05
this.image;
this.firstX = x;
this.firstY = y;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.width = 10;
this.height = 10;
this.velocity = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
this.acceleration = {
  x: this.ACCELERATION,
  y: 0
};
this.render = function(ctx) {
  if (typeof this.image != undefined) ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x - this.width / 2, this.y - this.height / 2);
  return this;
}
this.update = function() {
  this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x;
  this.velocity.y += this.acceleration.y;
  this.x += this.velocity.x;
  this.y += this.velocity.y;
  if (this.x >= this.firstX + this.MOVE_X_FROM_POSITION) {
    this.acceleration.x = -this.ACCELERATION;
  } else if (this.x <= this.firstX - this.MOVE_X_FROM_POSITION) {
    this.acceleration.x = +this.ACCELERATION;
  }
}
```

... and so on

I want the food to move 10 steps from it's first location one side and 10 steps the other side. The problem is that if the script is running longer it becomes to move far more than 10 steps from it's original position. PS: update function is called in the loop every 30 times per second

Where could be the problem? Thank You in advance

**EDIT**

Here is actually a demonstration of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/02jbmxnw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start in the middle, and move to the edge, until x <= 80, at which point you flip the direction of acceleration. Then you move to the opposite edge, until x >=100, and you flip the direction of acceleration.

The cause of the problem is this:
In the first run, you move from the 10 units from the centre before reversing. That means you have a runway of 10 units over which you are accelerating, with very little overshoot.

Then, you accelerate in the other direction until you hit x>=100, so you have a runway of 20 units over which you are accelerating. This means that when you hit X>=100, you're moving faster, and risk overshooting in that frame by a greater amount

So, the total runway each time you reverse, after the first, is 20units + overshoot. Since the runway is increasing each time, the top speed is also increasing, and thus the overshoot is increasing. This is a vicious cycle.

So, thats the problem. The solution will depend on the behaviour you want.
For a very simple solution, cap the velocity at a certain point:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
    velocity += acceleration;

    if(Math.abs(velocity) > maxVelocity){
        velocity -= acceleration;
    }
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vm1zz62k/

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the boundaries, you change the direction of the acceleration, but you do not set the velocity to 0. That means at the boundaries, the food will continue to move in the same direction, but slower and slower until it changes directions (when it's far past the original boundary).

I assume you want the swaying effect from acceleration, but if you don't, you can simply set the velocity to 0 as I've done here: https://jsfiddle.net/02jbmxnw/3/

If you do want the swaying effect from acceleration/deceleration, I recommend scaling the food's velocity from 100% to 0% (to -100%) based on the distance from it to a boundary (or its position between the boundaries).

Sorry if that was a bit confusing. Hope it helped though.